# Owl Carousel displaying different and wrong on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an owl.carousel on my website displaying testimonials. I didn't have any issues with this until about a month or two ago. I have no idea what happened that now I have this problem but i'll try to explain as best as I can.

I'm getting two different views of the carousel on the firefox and chrome. On firefox, it looks perfectly fine and displays correctly. On chrome how ever, it seems like after the browser cashes the page, the carousel decides to align all the text to the right (I know this is confusing so ill put picture in so you guys can see). The reason I say after it cashes the page is because, when I load the page with no cashe on chrome, it looks perfectly fine as it does on firefox, but as soon as I go to another page and then come back or refresh the page, the carousel all shifts to the right.

Here is what it looks like on chrome:

https://gyazo.com/2466dc69c470851122693d622975c018 --> Chrome

Here is also a link to the website for who ever that wants to read the code them selves (scroll down the home page and you will see the testimonials section):
http://ecocertificates.com.au

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys! 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @mlegg not sure how to post code. but ill copy paste the classes that the parent divs have. If you go to the page, you should be able to easily get the code?

Comment: fix the html errors, see this https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fecocertificates.com.au%2F